# a conjugate gradients result for eigenvalue estimates

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Consider the not preconditioned CG-method for a linear system $Ax=b$. 
Define $\beta_j = \frac{(r_{j+1},r_{j+1})}{(r_j,r_j)}$ and $\alpha_j=\frac{(r_j,r_j)}{(Ap_j,p_j)}$, where $(x,y) = y^Tx$ denotes the inner product, and $p_j=r_j+\beta_{j-1}p_{j-1}$, $p_0=r_0$.

Then the following holds:

$T_m=R_m^T A R_m$ where $R_m:=\left(\frac{r_0}{\|r_0\|},...,\frac{r_{m-1}}{\|r_{m-1}\|}\right)$ is the matrix with the residual vectors in each column and 
 $$T_m=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_0^{-1} & \frac{\sqrt\beta_0}{\alpha_0} & & &  \\
\frac{\sqrt\beta_0}{\alpha_0} & \frac{1}{\alpha_1} +\frac{\beta_0}{\alpha_0} & \ddots & & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & \frac{\beta_{m-2}}{\alpha_{m-2}} \\
& &  & \frac{\beta_{m-2}}{\alpha_{m-2}} & \frac{1}{\alpha_{m-1}}+\frac{\beta_{m-2}}{\alpha_{m-2}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I thought that, since $R_m$ is orthogonal, we can write $R_m^TAR_m=T_m$ as $A=R_mT_mR_m^T$ and simply calculate this, but this quickly got messy and confusing.

Hence: I tried induction over $m$. (**EDIT**: Since this led to confusion: I am trying to show the original proposition here, i.e. $T_m=R_m^TAR_m$, and not my - seemingly wrong - changed version aka $A=...$)

For $m=1$ the assumption obviously holds.

But - of course - I got stuck doing the calculation for $m\to m+1$. I tried a direct approach again, but quickyl lost track of what I'm doing.

How can I show this without having to calculate the matrix-products?  Any input is welcome :)
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is messy and confusing or not, but the problem is that it simply is NOT true. The matrix $T_m$ is a projection of $A$ onto the range of $R_m$. The matrix $A$ cannot be recovered as $A=R_mT_mR_m^T$. What you describe here is the Lanczos algorithm (recovered from CG): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm

Comment: Also, how can from $R^T_mAR_m=T_m$ follow $A=R_mT_mR_m^T$ for $m=1$? This cannot be true unless $A$ has rank 1.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel My notes say, that $R_m$ is orthogonal, hence I thought it must be invertible with $R_m^{-1}=R_m^T$ and that's how I got to $A=R_mT_mR_m^T$. With my induction - and I'm afraid I didn't point this out in my original post - I tried to show the original statement, $T_m=R_m^TAR_m$, and this is clearly true for $m=1$. I'll have a look at your link, hoping this helps me with the induction step!

Comment: $R_m$ has (in the exact arithmetic) orthogonal columns, which only means that $R_m^TR_m=I$ but $R_m$ need not to be square unless $m=n$. For the relation between the conjugate gradient and Lanczos methods, see, e.g., Section 6.7.3 (p. 201) of one of the classics: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation can actually be obtained directly from CG without any reference to the Lanczos algorithm. It is quite straightforward, but very tedious.
Let $P_m=[p_0,\ldots,p_m]$ and $R_m=[r_0/\|r_0\|,\ldots,r_m/\|r_m\|]$. Let also $S_j=\mathrm{diag}(\|r_0\|,\ldots,\|r_j\|)$, so that $R_mS_m$ is a matrix of non-normalized residual vectors. From $r_0=p_0$ and $r_j=p_j-\beta_{j-1}p_{j-1}$, $j=1,\ldots,m$, we have
$$
R_mS_m=P_mU_m, \quad
U_m=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\beta_0 &        & \\
  & \ddots   & \ddots &  \\
  &          & \ddots & -\beta_{j-1} \\
  &          &        & 1
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{1}
$$
The matrix $U_m$ is a nonsingular upper bidiagonal matrix with $1$ on the main diagonal and $-\beta_0,\ldots,-\beta_{j-1}$ on the first super-diagonal. Now consider $r_j=r_{j-1}-\alpha_{j-1}Ap_{j-1}$ for $j=0,\ldots,m+1$, from which we have
$$
AP_m=R_{m+1}S_{m+1}\underline{L}_{m+1,m}D_m^{-1},\tag{2}
$$
where $\underline{L}_{m+1,m}$ is an $(m+2)\times (m+1)$ matrix with $1$ on the main diagonal and $-1$ on the first sub-diagonal (hence a rectangular lower bidiagonal matrix), and $D_m=\mathrm{diag}(\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_m)$. Putting both (1) and (2) together leads to
$$
AR_mS_mU_m^{-1}=R_{m+1}S_{m+1}\underline{L}_{m+1,m}D_m^{-1}
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
AR_m=R_{m+1}S_{m+1}\underline{L}_{m+1,m}D_m^{-1}U_mS_m^{-1}.
$$
Now since $R_m^TR_{m+1}=[I,0]$ ($(m+1)\times(m+1)$ identity augmented by a zero vector, we get
$$ R_m^TAR_m=[I,0]S_{m+1}\underline{L}_{m+1,m}D_m^{-1}U_mS_m^{-1}
 =S_mL_mD_m^{-1}U_mS_m^{-1}, $$
where $L_m$ is the upper $(m+1)\times(m+1)$ part of $\underline{L}_{m+1,m}$, that is,
$$
L_m = \begin{bmatrix}
1  &        &    &   \\
-1 & \ddots &    &   \\
   & \ddots &  1 &   \\
   &        & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{(m+1)\times(m+1)}.
$$
Since $S_m$ and $D_m$ are diagonal and $L_m$ and $U_m$ are, respectively, lower and upper bidiagonal, the matrix $T_m$ is tridiagonal. To obtain the entries of $T_m$, "simply" compute the product :-) For the diagonal elements, we have
$$
(T_m)_{1,1} = \|r_0\|\frac{1}{\alpha_0}\frac{1}{\|r_0\|}=\frac{1}{\alpha_0}
$$
and for $i\geq 2$,
$$
(T_m)_{i,i} = \|r_{i-1}\|[-1,1]\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{i-2}^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha_{i-1}^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\beta_{i-2}\\1\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\|r_{i-1}\|}=
\frac{1}{\alpha_{i-1}}+\frac{\beta_{i-2}}{\alpha_{i-2}}.
$$
Similarly, the off-diagonal entries of $T_m$ can be evaluated using $\sqrt{\beta_{j-1}}=\|r_j\|/\|r_{j-1}\|$. Good luck :-)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Thank you, I was afraid that this was a very tedious calculation, but now I see the connection. Thanks!

Comment: @dinosaur Actually, it is somewhat easier to establish the equivalence of CG and Lanczos using the fact that the residuals of CG and the Lanczos vectors form an orthogonal basis of the same Krylov subspace (so that they are scalar multiples of each other). Then you can write a three-term recurrence for the CG residuals and compare it with the three-term recurrence for the Lanczos (where the coefficients of that recurrence are known to be the entries of the matrix $T$). The approach above, however, is (I guess) more elementary and does not require any reference to Lanczos.